# Error - functions: failed to create function dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

when i'm trying to deploy firebase function from my local machine i'm getting this error.

> functions: failed to create function dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment 
>   HTTP Error: 400, Default service account 'project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' doesn't exist. Please recreate this account (for example by disabling and enabling the Cloud Functions API), or specify a different account.

and the project that i'm trying to deploy is, https://github.com/actions-on-google/codelabs-nodejs/tree/master/level1-complete

Answer (score 1):

It seems your service account is removed. You may want to check whether your firebase & actions on google projects are removed or not.

If they are not, check for service accounts on [console.cloud.google.com](http://console.cloud.google.com) and make sure all your accounts are same as you are trying to deploy. (firebase, dialogflow, app-engine etc.) Also, disabling and enabling the Cloud Functions API may help as mentioned in error.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your error has 'project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'.

Shouldn't the project-id be your {project-id} from the google action that you created, and not the word project-id.

Comment: it was the actual project-id in the code, for understanding i have mentioned in the above question as project-id.